# Why Isn't Loki's Skin Blue

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, thor-marvel, loki

After Thor's banishment in the first movie we find out how Odin took pity on a frost giant baby who turns out to be Loki. It is also found out he is the son of Laufey who is the ruler of frost giants. Assuming he is a pure breed Frost Giant why isn't his son's skin blue. We see it briefly blue when Odin lifts Loki as a infant and then when Loki lifts the Casket of Ancient Winters. So why doesn't Loki share the color of his race and that of Asgard.

Answer (score 3):

Odin changed his appearance. You can see in the movie that as an infant Loki's skin was in fact blue but when Odin picked him up, he rubbed his face and changed his appearance. It's Odin's active power that keeps Loki's appearance as we see him. Odin was making plans for Loki's future as a bridge between Jötunheimr and Asgard even then.

Comment: Wouldn't Loki's own powers of illusion allow him to maintain his Asgardian appearance as well?

Comment: @DoctorWho22- Loki is a magic user but is basically a trickster who can cast illusions but I doubt for an extended period of time. Odin the All-father is the one with the power to change and maintain the appearance we see. Obviously Loki of Marvel can't change his appearance as the Loki of mythology can.

Comment: But that begs the question can Odin really keep up an illusion on Loki for extremely great distances?  Recall that Loki went to Jotunheim and Earth, yet still looked like an Asgardian.. His appearance even stayed Asgardian even as Odin was in his deep sleep.  Unless he placed a permanent enchantment on him, but the only clear indication of anything is that he changed skin color when Odin picked him up... For all we know Loki's inherent magic caused his skin to become the same as Odin's, unless there was a line that Odin said he did it himself.

Comment: @DoctorWho22 I don't think Odin's power has a range limit and it works even when he's in the Odinsleep.

Comment: Still unless it's stated that Odin directly used his power to change his skin, it's an assumption to think just because he picked him up and his skin changed it was Odin's power.  Like I said another explanation could be that Loki's inherent magic caused his skin to do so.

Comment: Well what about now that Odin is dead?